# importing registry artifacts in bulk in WSO2 EI 6.4

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

The way we handle multiple deploy environments in the company I'm currently working for is, for every project, to have a registry resources project and a composite application project *per environment*, together with a config project that holds the business logic. So for each project we have a 
ProjectRegistry.DEV/ProjectCompositeApp.DEV, ProjectRegistry.QA/ProjectCompositeApp.QA, ProjectRegistry.PRD/ProjectCompositeApp.PRD.
This structure makes it easy to keep track of the artifacts for each environment, but it can be a pain in the ass to keep. When a new registry project is created, we have to either create by hand or import each registry artifact, one by one, and even when we import we still have to manualy update the registry path to the artifact. Once you have a reasonable number of artifacts, this can take a while to do for all the environments.
There my question would be: is there any way to import registry artifacts in bulk? So that I could just create a new RegistryProject.QA and import all the artifacts from DEV? This would make things a lot easier.
Alternatively, do you use other way to organize registry artifacts by environment? I know a single registry project could be used, and environment-specific artifacts be identified by the name (_dev, _qa, etc) but I' not sure this would help things much.

Appreciate any inputs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can refer to the documentation on maintaining artifacts across multiple environments in the document [1].

[1]-https://wso2.com/library/articles/2014/03/development-and-deployment-of-c-app-based-artifacts-on-multiple-environments/